# "Balanced" vertex deletion on bipartite graphs

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

Given a bipartite graph $G = (X, Y, E)$ with $|X| = |Y|$, vertices from $X$ are to be deleted sequentially. As $d_x \le |X|$ vertices are deleted from $X$, let the total number of degree zero vertices of $Y$ be $d_y$. The goal is to seek a most "balanced" deletion, i.e., minimizing the maximum of $(d_x - d_y)$ for $d_x = 1, \ldots, |X|$.

For the setup, I would like to either find a polynomial time algorithm (seems less likely) for computing an optimal deletion sequence or show that the problem is hard (seems more likely). Does this problem map to some known problem(s)?